# Why is the first item returned by tracert not the default gateway?

Tags: windows, ip, windows-server-2008, tcp, netsh

I don't understand why the very first item returned by tracert is not the default gateway.

This is the output of `Get-NetIPConfiguration`

```
InterfaceAlias       : Ethernet
InterfaceIndex       : 4
InterfaceDescription : Intel(R) I210 Gigabit Network Connection
NetProfile.Name      : Network
IPv6Address          : 
IPv4Address          : 155.240.5.217
IPv6DefaultGateway   : 
IPv4DefaultGateway   : 155.240.5.254
DNSServer            : 1.1.1.1
                       1.0.0.1
```

When i do tracert:

```
tracert 1.1.1.1

Tracing route to 1dot1dot1dot1.cloudflare-dns.com [1.1.1.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  155.240.5.252
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  11.20.112.125
  3    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  11.82.1.12
  4    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  11.74.32.10
  5    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.76.249.4
  6     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  92.111.215.118
  7     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  linx-lon1.as13335.net [195.66.225.179]
  8    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  1dot1dot1dot1.cloudflare-dns.com [1.1.1.1]
```

Why is the very first item of tracert **155.240.5.252** instead of the ip of the default gateway **155.240.5.254**?

Answer (score 0):

Since default gateway is just a route entry which apply to every destinations but only has lowest priority, so most possible cause is that there is another route entry to 1.1.1.1 exist on the route table. You can simply use `route print -4` to confrim it.